# How do you return an optional value in an observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've been searching for a while about this. I'm creating my own observable. Is it possible to return an optional value from an observable?

For example:

```
public username: Observable<string?>
```

The goal is to return unknown when there isn't a user logged in, then emit a string when the user is logged in. Then emit unknown when logged back out. I could just emit an empty string for no user, but I don't like that form.

Comment: You can just return `null` if there is no user. `null` and empty string has clear distinct function and meanings.

Comment: I'd like to stick to optional types. I came from languages that are optional driven and prefer not to use null. I understand how you can use null. I also do strict null checking. I prefer strongly typed languages, hence the question.

Comment: There is really no such thing as "optional" for `Observables`, per se. It's a stream of events. In your case. if you subscribe to your `username` observable, the observable will emit a value if it calls its `.next()` method. Simply put, there should be no values if there is no user. Maybe it's better to not emit anything if there is no user, and emit some string if there is user? Then your `subscriber` can just react to what is being emitted.

Comment: Thank you for that input. I'll give it a try. The only drawback is I want to emit something to say "he logged out" at which point it goes back to its original text. I'm currently doing that with a blank string, just not a huge fan of it.

Comment: You could make your `username` into a model and then pass an instance of the model with optional property to signal there is nothing.